# Intercept android/blackberry next/prev buttons

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, blackberry

Both the BB Z10 and the Samsung Galaxy phones have a 'next' and 'prev' button at the top of their virtual keyboard (as seen in the image below). They functionally seem to work as 'tab' and 'shift-tab' respectively but they don't seem to have their own keycodes.

[image: An example of the next/prev buttons]

The site I'm building has a multi-part form which is actually a single part form, separated out using JavaScript and CSS. I don't have the option to alter this functionality. However the prev/next buttons will happily cycle through all parts of the form, regardless of if they are mandatory or not. I'm not even sure how this button manages to bypass validation as I've got a function which prevents an item losing focus without being validated first.

Is there a way to intercept or disable the functionality of those buttons so I can prevent the user getting through the form without filling in any data?

Note: Please don't provide alternate or better solutions, I know this way of working is far from ideal. I'm not in control of this project and I can't change the code very much at all. I literally just want an answer to this question.